# Bitbucket - доступ НА ЗАПИСЬ одной машине в один проект

Tags: git, bitbucket

Есть бесплатный аккаунт Bitbucket с несколькими проектами. Создаю новый проект, хочу открыть доступ НА ЗАПИСЬ для одной определенной машины (указав SSH-ключ этой машины).

В настройках проекта вижу только раздел Access keys, где можно открыть доступ НА ЧТЕНИЕ для определенных машин (указанием SSH-ключей этих машин).
В общих настройках аккаунта в разделе SSH keys, можно открыть доступ НА ЗАПИСЬ ВО ВСЕ ПРОЕКТЫ определенным машинам (указанием SSH-ключей этих машин).

Как открыть доступ НА ЗАПИСЬ в одном определенном проекте для одной определенной машины (указав SSH-ключ этой машины, без указания пользователей и групп Bitbucket)?

Comment: Спросите у них, https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket/

Comment: а как сразу приходящий в голову обходной путь — создайте нового пользователя, а от его имени — хранилище.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да ладно вам, это же простая операция, без техподдержки легко делается.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, если ключи закрепляются не (только) за пользователем, а (и) за хранилищем, тогда, действительно, техподдержку спрашивать не надо.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin мне кажется, именно для этой задачи и была реализована такая возможность. Пишут: "Access keys provide a simple way **for other systems** to...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта инструкция позволит вам дать доступ на чтение и запись в конкретный проект по SSH-ключу.

1. Откройте нужный проект (репозиторий) в веб-интерфейсе Bitbucket.
2. В боковом меню нажмите кнопку с шестеренкой или надписью **Settings**. Откроется страница настроек проекта.
3. На этой странице в боковом меню, в группе **Security** нажмите ссылку **Access keys**. Откроется страница управления ключами.

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. На странице управления ключами нажмите кнопку **Add key**. Откроется окно добавления ключа.
5. В окне добавления ключа выберите опцию Permission: **Read / Write**, в текстовое поле ниже скопируйте публичную часть ключа (содержимое файла `.pub`).

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Нажмите **Add key**, чтобы сохранить ключ.

Теперь этот ключ позволяет производить чтение и запись **в данный репозиторий**. Доступ к иным проектам не затронут, его можно настроить отдельно таким же способом.

Comment: *pbcopy* — о, интерфейс детектит операционную систему и предлагает нужную команду! интересно, что для gnu/linux там предлагается?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, на гитхабе и гитлабе тоже есть такой трюк. Зайдите в инструкцию на любом из них.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin У меня там нет опции Permission: Read / Write: https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=ee01f853dee5de8cbdaa69c52b6ae714

Comment: @Александр действительно, на bitbucket.org у меня тоже нет такой опции. Создайте пользователя спецально для машины, зарегистрируйте ее ключ в пользователе, добавьте пользователя в проект.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin
>>> действительно, на bitbucket.org у меня тоже нет такой опции <<<

А где у Вас она есть?

Comment: @Александр на self-hosted, т.е. на своем сервере и по лицензии.

Comment: @Александр получилось через отдельного пользователя решить задачу?

Comment: Уже нет такого. Этот удаленный репозиторий позиционирует себя как соцсеть, потому получится только через регистрацию отдельного пользователя.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра причем тут соцсеть? В учетках с бесплатным тарифным планом на bitbucket.org нельзя добавлять ключи с правом на запись. В [комментарии выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685121/bitbucket-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%9d%d0%90-%d0%97%d0%90%d0%9f%d0%98%d0%a1%d0%ac-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82/685195#comment1008810_685195) так и написано.